# How to differentiate between head voice and falsetto?

Tags: voice

What are the characteristics used to determine if something is sung in head voice or if is falsetto?

If we take the line “No, I don't want to fall in love…”  from Chris Isaak's Wicked Game, is this performed using true head voice or rather falsetto voice?

Comment: before this gets closed for being off-topic... it's not falsetto, so I guess it must be 'head voice' - though that's a term I've never got to grips with, personally. It's a song I sing often & I have no falsetto range at all, zero [if I can reach it I can reach it full voice]. It's just a controlled 'full-voice' as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Edited to try make on topic. See also http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/why-is-this-getting-so-many-close-votes.

Comment: To whoever will answer this question: please make sure to make a distinction between female and male voices. The two work quite differently when head voice and falsetto are concerned.

Comment: Interestingly, form what I have heard, while the "traditional" vocal trainer view is that women don't have falsetto, there is a controversial counter-claim based on evidence that in fact, their vocal chords are quite capable of vibrating in the same way as a man's falsetto. It has just never been recognized as such, because the timbre change is not as drastic as it is with women.

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername Thank you for your editing and your hint at the discussion on META!

Comment: Why would this be off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My inexperienced ears tell me the high sound is disconnected from the low. Plus, the high sound is pretty thin. Thus, I don't see it as head voice.

Going a bit off topic: Head voice is a tricky concept. I have just covered it with my vocal teacher and, to be honest, it's not something you should force yourself to do. It is something that comes naturally as you go up the scales if:

- your throat is free (hard to achieve that)
- psychologically, you do not think about having to reach to hit the high note

It's almost counter-intuitive that, the way to hit a high(-er) note in head voice is by not thinking/concentrating on the fact that it's high, but that's how it works.