# My falsetto sounds like normal chest voice and doesn't sound like falsetto at all. Any help?

Tags: voice, falsetto

*I've seen other questions in various forums, YouTube videos, and other sources on the internet like:*  [How can I tell if I (or other male singers) are using falsetto or head voice?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/39819/how-can-i-tell-if-i-or-other-male-singers-are-using-falsetto-or-head-voice?noredirect=1&lq=1)

*But they don't answer my question because what I'm dealing with is that (maybe, I don't have any prior knowledge with falsetto so I can't say for sure) I can differentiate headvoice and falsetto but the actual problem is not the differentiation between headvoice & falsetto,* **but my falsetto doesn't sound like a released sound to me, and my friend (who don't know anything about vocal/music) says it doesn't sound like it stands out from my normal singing voice and sounds like my normal singing voice.**

So I followed this tutorial on how to find my own falsetto/headvoice:

https://tarasimonstudios.com/how-to-find-your-falsetto/

*"The Location: When singing in your head voice, you will feel the resonance in the upper portion or mask area of your head. The exact placement will depend on your anatomy,* **but you will feel it anywhere from your nasal passages up into your forehead."**

And I practiced some exercises I randomly found on the internet to find my headvoice/falsetto

and found my headvoice/falsetto (I don't have any prior experience singing in falsetto, so I don't know and couldn't say anything) **in around my "nasal" that Tara Simons talks about in her tutorial.**

I've also tried inhaling from my belly (diaphragmatic breathing) (I mean, I tried to deeply breathe from my diaphragm, but I guess I still lack in breath support so I need to work on it)

I started to sing *Creep* by Radiohead (at 2:26):

to test the high notes in falsetto, at my very first attempts it was weak, but as I improve my breathing it starts to not become weak.

**But the problem is my friend** *(who's just an ordinary person who doesn't know anything about music/singing)* **said my falsetto doesn't sound like falsetto, but just like normal singing voice and my falsetto sound doesn't stand out from my normal singing voice like a usual falsetto sound like** *(like those famous male singers who sings in falsetto*).

I'm confused, does it have to do with resonance/lack of breath support/larynx position?

I tried raising my larynx up to my highest natural larynx range (not forcing above) and my friend says it sounds more falsetto than before, but I feel like this is very unnatural but I don't know.

Is it that I just have to work on breath support, placement and resonance more? **Also, I haven't done anything about resonance at all. I just simply sing the falsetto with a bit (still lacking, and I'm working on it) diaphragmatic breathing support.**

*Any help is greatly appreciated!*